# What is meant by TTL in this context?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level, specifications

Regarding [this](https://www.teamwavelength.com/download/Datasheets/pldseries.pdf) driver manual, the analog input has range 0-5 V with 1 MΩ input impedance. But the manual also writes that the analog input is not TTL compatible:

[image]

I thought the term "TTL compatible" is about voltage level. But what does it mean in this context? Do they mean the input is not for open collector input but for push-pull input?

Comment: A guess: some customers used this input as an on/off laser switch, and killed their laser by overdriving it... **analog input** was insufficient warning that should've said *don't use logic levels here*.

Comment: How would they overdrive it? Can you give example?

Comment: @GNZ by putting 5V on it, causing the current setpoint to go straight to the max.

Comment: Datasheet specs 5v as a safe input. The absolute max is 5.5v, meaning there are likely protection diodes. They also spec a 0->5v response in the datasheet, so i don't think it's voltage that is the concern. Possibly they're concerned at the high frequency edge of the TTL signal interfering with the driver (the analog input is relatively slow). There is a lot in the datasheet about noise, decoupling, etc. The device may be sensitive to high frequency noise generally.

Comment: @user1850479 5V is safe *for the controller*. It's not necessarily safe for the device being controlled.

Answer (score 0):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic#Interfacing_considerations) on TTL (or better, the fat orange TTL Databook if you have one).

TTL requires that logic 1 input must be at least 2V, and TTL drivers are designed to guarantee that. That is far short of what this driver requires to register as logic 1.

Comment: Isnt it an unnecessary statement for an analog input then?

Comment: @GNZ - I agree.  I don't know why they would have this statement in there.  They could fill a whole page listing what that input is NOT compatible with.

Comment: @GNZ  I'd guess they have other components that do have TTL compatible inputs. [LDTC0520/LDTC1020](https://www.teamwavelength.com/download/Datasheets/ldtc1020.pdf)

Comment: @GNZ I think Some laser controllers accept either analog or PWM on the same input. Without reading this datasheet too closely, if analog, you are correct, but if PWM, the input level should conform to HCMOS rather than TTL.